# Post to Facebook user's groups using Graph Api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to know how to build a Facebook application that can allow me to post a specific message to all the Facebook users that are connected to this application. I searched a lot but I couldn't get an answer for this, I found a lot of applications that helps me send a message to MY groups only. What I need is when a user goes to my application and press **Login With Facebook** and give my application the required permission, a preset message is sent to all the groups he is a member of. Something like when I get connected to a game application, the application sends "*Mrs. ... started playing .. game*" to the groups I'm a member of.

Answer (score 1):

> I found a lot of applications that helps me send a message to MY
>   groups only

My is relative (like the "me" endpoint). Hence, anyone that logs into that app it will work for THEIR groups. Which is what you're wanting to do.

But beware: the functionality you're describing would fall under the definition of spam, as its the same post made for multiple groups without regard to the audience. Posts should only be in groups that cover a relevant population or subject matter. You'll get your app shut down for what you're describing.

Comment: "My is relative (like the "me" endpoint). Hence, anyone that logs into that app it will work for THEIR groups. Which is what you're wanting to do." I understand this, but im talking about applications like this [link](http://apps.facebook.com/posterbyroomi/) .. but i don't want this .. i want the message to be sent to the user groups as he clicks on "login with facebook" button

Comment: You are not to post to groups or walls without the specific approval of the user. Sorry, I will not help with this project any further, as your descriptions sound like spam.